# Cannot figure out how to combine two tables using an intermediate id table

Tags: mysql

I have a journal system that I am currently developing.
There are some tables:

**Table 1: issues**

```
issueid | issue_title
      1 | November 2016
```

**Table 2: articles**

```
articleid | issueid | article_title
        1 |       1 | Yet another article title
```

**Table 3: authors**

```
authorid | firstname | lastname
       1 | John      | Doe
       2 | Jack      | Foe
```

**Table 4: articlesauthors**

```
authorarticleid | authorid | articleid 
              1 |        1 |         1
              2 |        2 |         1
```

The table `articlesauthors` have the records which author authoring which article.

Now I need to get all the articles with the authors for a specific issue. It should be something like this but cannot figure it out, as I mentioned:

```
SELECT  i.issue_title, ar.article_title, au.firstname, au.lastname 
FROM articles ar
INNER JOIN articlesauthors aa1 ON aa1.articleid = ar.articleid
INNER JOIN articlesauthors aa2 ON aa2.articleid = au.authorid
INNER JOIN issues i ON i.issueid = ar.issueid
WHERE i.issueid = 1
```

Well I am stuck here that I do not know where the type `authors` table in the query.

Desired output should be like this:

```
issue_title   | article_title | firstname | lastname
November 2... | Yet anothe... | John      | Doe
November 2... | Yet anothe... | Jack      | Foe
```

Comment: please place some sample data and your required output

Comment: What is the problem with the query?

Comment: `au` is undefined in your SQL.

Comment: The query in the question is not a working query. It is just a draft to be enhanced by the other  SO users.

Comment: nice. It's expensive to employ people to write your code for you.

Comment: @Martin Thank you for your advice. Your comment is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the modified SQL query :

```
SELECT ar.article_title, aut.firstname, aut.lastname 
FROM issues as issue 
INNER JOIN articles as ar ON ar.issueid = issue.issueid 
INNER JOIN articlesauthors as aa ON ar.articleid = aa.articleid 
INNER JOIN authors as aut ON aut.authorid = aa.authorid
WHERE issue.issueid = 1
```

This will result in expected output.

Comment: Thanks this is also working. Tested. Same result shows up.

Answer (score 0):

according to your posted query, your are using three tables only. you want to get auther firstname and lastname but your are not joining auther table(you are selecting au.firstname ,au.lastname but au id not defined)..try with the below query

```
select article_title,firstname,lastname from articles
inner join  articlesauthors on articlesauthors.articleid=articles.articleid
inner join auther on auther.authorid=articlesauthors.authorid
inner join issue on issue.issueid=articles.issueid
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to write the `issue_title` column into the `SELECT` part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Well thinking a few minutes brought me the solution.

```
SELECT  i.issue_title, ar.article_title, au.firstname, au.lastname 
FROM articles ar
INNER JOIN articlesauthors aa ON aa.articleid = ar.articleid
INNER JOIN authors au ON aa.authorid = au.authorid
INNER JOIN issues i ON i.issueid = ar.issueid
WHERE i.issueid = 1
```

Now this query brings me correct dataset.